# Showing $\pi$ is irrational using taylor's theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, irrational-numbers, pi, rationality-testing

To prove the irrationality of $$e = \sum ^\infty _ {n=0} \frac{1}{n!}$$ we can show that $e \lt 3$ by using a suitable geometric series. By Taylor's theorem (applied to $a=0$ and $b=1$) we know that, 
$$ e-\sum ^n _{k=0} \frac{1}{n!} = R_n = e^\alpha \frac {1}{\bigl(n+1\bigl)!} $$
for some $\alpha$ such that $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$. Since $e \lt 3$, $R_n \lt \frac{3}{(n+1)!}.$ Now suppose that $e$ is a rational number $\frac{c}d$ where $c$ and $d$ are co-prime. For $n=d$ we see that $d! R_d \in Z$. On the other hand, using the estimate for $R_d$ that we have obtained using Taylor's theorem, $$d! R_d \lt \frac{d! \cdot 3}{(d+1)}! \lt 1$$ if $d \geq 2$
How can I show $\pi$ is irrational using similar ideas?

Comment: There is a method, but kind of complicated, at least more complicated than this, and the method is not using similar idea. You may google it.

Comment: You might want to look at [Niven's proof that $\pi$ is irrational](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788).

Comment: None of these seem to take the approach you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_π_is_irrational

Comment: A mild warning: Over 90 per cent of the text in your question is in an image, and hence not searchable. This presses people's buttons here. Do study [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). About your question, the Taylor series having values related to $\pi$ often represent inverse trig functions, and don't have those nice factorials in the denominators of the coefficients. Therefore irrationality of $\pi$ needs a different technique,

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen as I'am very new to stackexchange i want to ask how to type symbols in mathematics. I'am facing difficulty while asking questions / commenting etc.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen about question. It is part of that question that i excluded in screenshot. Check out this optional exercise in Tutorial Sheet 3 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gv5oT1umR0OGL0zmjvBFiAP4IOdm5sNb?usp=sharing

Comment: See [our guide to MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619) for tips in using this wonderful way of typesetting math. You may be overwhelmed if you try to absorb all of it one sitting. Start with simple things.

Comment: Sorry, I don't visit google drives. Last time I tried I couldn't see anything, because I block cookies from google. I try to keep the information google can collect on my person at a minimum, and (because my cell phone is running on Android) need to be extra careful.

Comment: +1 for @JyrkiLahtonen last comment. It's best not to use Google drive links.